# What is the best way to design a date/time picker that requires an input for minutes and seconds?

Tags: forms, datetimepicker

I’m working on a Date/Time picker that I’d to get feedback on.  See my 2 ideas below. This design is based off of Google Cal. (I know Google throws a lot of $$$ at UX so I figured this would be a good place to start). A few things…

1. All the fields are dropdowns as well as manual inputs.
2. An input for Seconds is required in the UI. Inputting seconds is not used often.
3. Start and End times can vary. There is no evidence that most start/end times happen at the top of the hour.[image: date and time picker ideas]

Comment: Depends on the context of the usage... are you also depending a calendar application?

Comment: Hey Michael, yes there would be a calendar flyout when you click on the date. I should have pointed this out in the designs.

Comment: Test several options with your users... They will tell you which one they understand the best and prefer.

Comment: There are three common ways to specify a date-time span, i.e. start to end, start and duration or duration and end. Are you sure your users prefer the single one you’re offering them? Furthermore, a drop-down with 24 choices for what can be done by entering one or two digits seems like a bad idea. Did you consider a clock face and AM/PM toggle instead (as your audience seems to be US-only)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the second one. With the first choice, it is not very obvious that the user can manually input time. Assuming precise time is important to the application, you want to make it immediately clear that they should be precise, which the longer picker does. If you want to go with the shorter option, make sure it looks like a control that the user can edit, i.e. a text box.

Comment: Thanks Milesper, appreciate the feedback. I agree with your logic here. Can you think of a design that is better than this? I'm certainly open to ideas here. If not, I'll go with the second one. :) Cheers